# How to tackle this? Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not sure what is going wrong, it seems to work on windows but not mac. Any help is appreciated!

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(foreign)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(zoo)
library(dynlm)
theme_set(theme_bw())

df <- read.csv("BTC-USD.csv")
df <- na.omit(df)
df$Adj.Close <- ts(df$Adj.Close)
```

```
df$Date <- seq.Date(as.Date('2014-10-01'), by = 'day', length.out = length(df$Adj.Close))

str(df)
ggplot(df, aes(y = Adj.Close, x = Date )) + geom_line(col = 'red') +
  labs(title = 'Adjusted Daily Close', ylab = 'return')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error is returned when a process that is expecting numeric data finds factor (or similar). Try setting your variables to numeric (using function 'as.numeric') and see if that fixes it.